# How many sequences are there?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I saw this problems in an combinatorics exam:
\begin{array}{l}For\;all\;n\geq0,\;find\;the\;number\;of\;integer\:sequences\;a_0,...,a_{2n}\;,\;a_0=a_{2n}=1\;\\and\;for\;all\;1\leq i\leq2n\;we\;have\;\frac{a_i}{a_{i-1}}\in\{\frac16,\frac23,\frac32,6\}\end{array}

It reminds me similar problems regarding Catalan numbers, but i didn't find a connection in this case.

Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: $$Why\; type \; like\; this?$$

Comment: Interpret this as a walk on a two-dimensional grid , with one axis measured by powers of $2$, and the other by powers of $3$, so that the integer point $(p,q)$ corresponds to the quantity $2^p3^q$. Now what kind of walk on this integer grid corresponds to an integer sequence of the kind you are describing? How can you count the number of such walks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hint of @TeresaLisbon is nice. We generalise the set
\begin{align*}
\left\{\frac{1}{2\cdot3},\frac{2}{3},\frac{3}{2},2\cdot 3\right\}
\end{align*}
and denoting with $[z^n]$ the coefficient of $z^n$ of a series we consider

> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[x^0y^0]}&\color{blue}{\left(xy+\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}+\frac{1}{xy}\right)^{2n}}\\
> &=[x^0y^0]\left(x\left(y+\frac{1}{y}\right)+\frac{1}{x}\left(y+\frac{1}{y}\right)\right)^{2n}\\
> &=[x^0y^0]\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{2n}\left(y+\frac{1}{y}\right)^{2n}\\
> &=\left([x^0]\frac{1}{x^{2n}}\left(1+x^{2}\right)^{2n}\right)^2\\
> &=\left([x^{2n}]\sum_{j=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{j}x^{2j}\right)^2\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\binom{2n}{n}^2}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>
> We conclude from (1) the number of valid sequences of length $2n+1$ is the square of the *[central binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient)* $\color{blue}{\binom{2n}{n}^2}$.

The *[Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number)* $C_n=\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}=\binom{2n}{n}-\binom{2n}{n-1}$ can be written as the difference of the central binomial coefficient with a shifted binomial coefficient. The relationship with (1) don't be to seem very close.

**Lattice paths:** Let's look at a graphic with lattice paths for small values $n=1$ and $n=2$ to better see what's going on.

[image]

We consider logarithmically scaled axis with unit $2$ in $x$-direction and unit $3$ in $y$-direction.

- The top left part in grey shows an element $a_i=\left(2^2,3^6\right)$ and the four directed edges weighted with $\left\{6,\frac{3}{2},\frac{1}{6},\frac{2}{3}\right\}$ which point to a candidate $a_{i+1}$.
- The bottom blue part with element $a_j=\left(2^3,3^2\right)$ in the center shows all valid subsequences of length $2$ starting and ending in $a_j$. We start in $a_j$ and there are $4$ ways to make a step of length $1$ according to the grey part and then we go back to $a_j$. We obtain this way
  \begin{align*}
  \color{blue}{\binom{2n}{n}^2=\binom{2}{1}^2=4}
  \end{align*}
  valid paths and therefore $4$ valid sequences.
- The right-hand green part with element $a_k=\left(2^7,3^4\right)$ in the center shows all valid subsequences of length $4$ starting and ending in $a_k$. We see for instance there are $9$ valid paths starting in $a_k=\left(2^7,3^4\right)$ and ending in $\left(2^8,3^5\right)$ followed by one final step back to $a_k$.

  - These $9$ paths are weighted with

\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{cccccc}
6&\frac{1}{6}&6&\qquad xy&\frac{1}{xy}&xy\\
\frac{2}{3}&\frac{3}{2}&6&\qquad\frac{x}{y}&\frac{y}{x}&xy\\
\frac{3}{2}&\frac{2}{3}&6&\qquad\frac{y}{x}&\frac{x}{y}&xy\\
\frac{1}{6}&6&6&\qquad xy&\frac{1}{xy}&xy\\
\\
\frac{3}{2}&6&\frac{2}{3}&\qquad \frac{y}{x}&xy&\frac{x}{y}\\
6&\frac{3}{2}&\frac{2}{3}&\qquad xy&\frac{x}{y}&\frac{y}{x}\\
\\
\frac{3}{2}&6&\frac{2}{3}&\qquad \frac{y}{x}&xy&\frac{x}{y}\\
\frac{2}{3}&6&\frac{3}{2}&\qquad \frac{x}{y}&xy&\frac{y}{x}\\
\\
6&6&\frac{1}{6}&\qquad xy&xy&\frac{1}{xy}
\end{array}
\end{align*}

and $4$ times this set of paths results in
\begin{align*}
\color{green}{\binom{2n}{n}^2=\binom{4}{2}^2=36}
\end{align*}
valid paths and therefore $36$ valid sequences.